# Apigility Zend: Get Authentication Service Using Key Name

Tags: zend-framework2, laminas-api-tools

I have setup database adapter in config and I can get database service in Factory using key name like:

```
$connectDb = $services->get('connectDb');
```

and then I have setup authentication adapter with key name: 'connectoauth2'
It is working fine and authenticate my rest api.

The problem is I want to inject this 'connectoauth2' to my UserEducation Service to getIdentity in So I did in Factory as

```
$connectDb = $services->get('connectDb');
$connectOAuth2 = $services->get('connectoauth2'); // --> service is not found
$service = new \ConnectApp\Service\UserEducation($connectDb, $connectOAuth2);
return new UserEducationResource($service);
```

ERROR: Unable to resolve service "connectoauth2" to a factory; are you certain you provided it during configuration?

Even authentication is working fine but Still I can't get Service as i did for database.

Please help!

Thanks!

Comment: will need to see the code you've used to configure it..

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that `$services` is the service manager? If it is another service locator instance (for example a `ControllerManager` or `ViewHelperManager` and not the service manager) you will first have to get the service manager from that service locator:

```
$serviceManager = $services->getServiceLocator();
```

and then your service from the service manager:

```
$service = $serviceManager->get('connectoauth2');
```

Check for an overview of all the other service locators also [here](https://akrabat.com/zendservicemanager-configuration-keys/)

Answer (score 0):

That is just `Authentication Adapter` not `Authentication Service`. So if you need to retrieve `identity` from `Authentication`, you should using `Authentication Service`. In Zend Framework, you can call `Authentication Service` like this

```
$authentication = $serviceManager->get('authentication');
```

And retrieve the `identity` like this.

```
$authentication->getIdentity()
```